# Get timestamp of week returns NaN

Tags: javascript, c#, timestamp, nan

I am trying to get a timestamp of the week, starting on a monday, similar to this C# script:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
now = DateTime.UtcNow.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
int weekday = (int)(now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

This returns: 1548633600

When trying this in javascript I get NaN error:

```
var d = new Date();
var w = Date.UTC(thisYear, thisMonth, d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + 1), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var weekDay = Math.floor(w / 1000);
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Hoping for help :-)

Comment: Use `new Date().getTime() / 1000`?

Comment: **it would be obvious why if you at least try to debug code**  ... `w` is NaN why? because of putting result of `d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + 1)` as day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getUTCDay();

var utcTime = Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate() - day + 1);
var weekDay = utcTime / 1000;

console.log(weekDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: this returns Friday, update it to get Monday

```
var t = new Date().getDate() + (6 - new Date().getDay() - 1) - 7 ;
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(t);
var lastFriday = d;
console.log(lastFriday);
```